# Array Wrapper Class

Tags: performance, array, vba, reinventing-the-wheel, collections

I’ve wrote a small array wrapper class which mimics the built-in Collection for adding and retrieving items. Once the object is created, you set the array capacity and that would not change.

```
'// ArrayList Class

Private arr() As String
Private position As Long

' Add
Public Sub Add(ByVal Value As String)
    arr(position) = Value
    position = position + 1
End Sub

' Count
Public Function Count() As Long
    Count = UBound(arr)
End Function

' Item
Public Function Item(ByVal Index As Long) As String
    Item = arr(Index)
End Function

' SetCapacity
Public Sub SetCapacity(ByVal arrsize As Long)
    ReDim arr(arrsize)
End Sub
```

Testing the object:

```
Sub TestArrayList()

    Dim a As ArrayList
    Set a = New ArrayList
        a.SetCapacity 4

        a.Add "One"
        a.Add "Two"
        a.Add "Three"
        a.Add "Four"
        a.Add "Five"

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To a.Count
        Debug.Print a.Item(i)
    Next i
End Sub

'Output as expected
'One
'Two
'Three
'Four
'Five
```

It is widely known that expensive operations of an array are `ReDim Preserve` where a new array is created and the items of the old array are being copied.

In the object above, we only create a new array when calling the `SetCapacity(arrsize)` method. No need to preserve any items. Thus the expensive operation here is the creation of the new array (fixed size) which is only performed once.

The question in terms of speed and overhead is: would a built-in collection be more appropriate than the above wrapper object?

The aim is to create a Collection of objects but I'm not sure which would be more appropriate, a `Collection(Of Collection)` or a `Collection(Of ArrayList)`.

In terms of data, the ArrayList will hold around 16 elements and the Collection around 1,500 objects.

Comment: Why not use a `Scripting.Dictionary`?

Comment: @ThunderFrame Thanks but what is the benefit of using a dictionary in this case? I still need a collection (or dictionary) that holds arrays (or collections).

Comment: Can't see any advantage from using a plain array - Ok, position is automatic while Adding...

Comment: What do you mean by "In terms of data, the ArrayList will hold around 16 elements and the Collection around 1,500 objects."?  `Count` should equal `position - 1`.    You could add a `getCapacity`  method that equals `arr(arrsize)` but in the VBA  
I would make`Capacity` a property.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina I mean the Collection will hold around 1,500 ArrayList objects and each ArrayList will hold around 15-16 elements (strings).

Comment: @KostasK. 24K elements is fairly trivial and hardly worth optimizing.

Comment: If you want to emulate your own ArrayList class for the learning experience, you might want to look at my post [VBA Class to Encapsulate the System.Collections.ArrayList Class](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/178280/vba-class-to-encapsulate-the-system-collections-arraylist-class) .

Comment: Another thing to consider is that built-in Collections, Dictionaries, ArrayList ...etc. are written in a low level programming language intrinsically faster than anything we can write in the VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hold issue with the way you determine your wrapper's size -

> ```
> Public Sub SetCapacity(ByVal arrsize As Long)
>     ReDim arr(arrsize)
> End Sub
> ```

The `arrsize` I pass will be 0-based, so if I want 5, I have to put 4. Not intuitive. Instead

```
RedDim arr(1 to arrsize)
```

And then there's not really any reason for this

> ```
> Public Function Count() As Long
>     Count = UBound(arr)
> End Function
> ```

Because your iterations would be `LBound(arr) to Ubound(arr)`.

---

Also, I think holding the position in a class level variable is kind of sloppy. Like was mentioned in the comments, there are built-in objects that can do this for you - there's no real reason to reinvent the wheel here.